# Ошибка Flash CS5 error initializing java runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, java, flash, actionscript

Всем привет. Вчера установил Adobe Flash CS5, но при запуске выскакивает ошибка Error initializing java runtime. Погуглил но ничего работающего не нашел. На сколько я понял на java написан компилятор для ActionScript3.Отказаться от as3 и от flash cs5 не могу,так как работаю в FlashBuilder, и для рисования элементов управления он использует именно flash cs5. Никто не знает как решить эту проблему с jre?

Answer (score 1):

вылетает при запуске CS5 или при попытке запустить из него swf? Сам работаю во FlashDevelop и одно время линковал его к CS5, периодически выдавало ту же ошибку. С actionscript можно (и удобно) работать в другой, внешней IDE. А из CS5 данные публиковать в SWC-библиотеку и подключать её. Кстати не заметил каких-то кардианльных отличий CS5 от CS4 (с т.з. программера наверно они незначительны).
FlashBuilder практически не использовал, но подозреваю, что он прекрасно работает с SWC. На крайняк можно попробовать поменять IDE.

И еще. от безысходности бы поковырялся в Java Control Panel. Там могут быть какие-то спасительные настройки. Например, попробовать отключить java quick starter или т.п..

Comment: С помощью Cs5 я swc копилил. Но компилятор as3 написан на java. сам по себе cs5 работает, но вот компилить не хочет. мне он нужен для рисования элементов(чего fb делать не может),а нарисованные элементы использую в fb. И нужен именно cs5 потому что он подкручен под работу с fb.

а как может java quick starter влиять на работу?

и кстати не знаешь как урезать выделяемую для jre память?

Comment: отключение quick starter как раз несколько урезает память на jre. но это исключительно интуитивные соображения (стартер влияет на скорость инициализации джава-приложений, а значит и на процесс инициализации в целом), в принципе я сомневаюсь, что эти соображения помогут:)
Я не понимаю, в чем беда, если у тебя компилится swc в CS5. Нарисовал что надо, скомпилил в swc, подключил этот swc к fb как библиотеку.. Или fb не снабжен компилятором swf?.. Раньше FlexBuilder вроде бы не требовал запущенного CS'а для работы. Теперь требует?

Comment: cs5 отказывается компилить swc ,в этом то и проблема